# multiple booleans against a string

Tags: python, formatting, boolean

I am trying to run a check again multiple words in a user-input string :

```
prompt = input("What would you like to know?")
if ('temperature' and 'outside') in prompt:
```

I initially was trying to check against `'outside'` and `('temperature' or 'weather')` but I run into the same issue both ways.  The code does not return `true` if I enter only `'temperature'`, but it returns `true` if I enter only `'outside'`.

Is there a piece of formatting I am missing to get it to check against both text values rather than just the one?

Comment: You didn't include a language tag; is it Python? If not, please add the appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the unexpected behavior you see is that `and` has higher precedence here; and that is because `in` can only have one expression on the left side.

So what happens is `'temperature' and 'outside'` is evaluated. The semantics of `and` is such that if its left side operand is truthy (and all non-empty strings are), the value of the whole expression will be equal to the right operand (in this case, `'outside'`):

```
In [1]: 'weather' and 'outside'
Out[1]: 'outside'
```

So what you do is equivalent to checking `if 'outside' in prompt`.

---

Instead, you could do:

```
if 'temperature' in prompt and 'outside' in prompt:
    ...
```

or more generally:

```
words = ['temperature', 'outside']
if all(word in prompt for word in words):
    ...
```

to combine conditions:

```
words = ['temperature', 'weather']
if 'outside' in prompt and any(word in prompt for word in words):
   ...
```